# Compile error "Missing \endcsname inserted." with code and tcolorbox

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I get this error when trying to compile into pdf my document. It is important to know that my project did compile a month ago without errors: I opened it today and it fails without being modified at all. I include a MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[breakable,listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{varioref}

\definecolor{base03}{HTML}{002B36}
\definecolor{base02}{HTML}{073642}
\definecolor{base01}{HTML}{586E75}
\definecolor{base00}{HTML}{657B83}
\definecolor{base0}{HTML}{839496}
\definecolor{base1}{HTML}{93A1A1}
\definecolor{base2}{HTML}{EEE8D5}
\definecolor{base3}{HTML}{FDF6E3}
\definecolor{yellow}{HTML}{B58900}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{CB4B16}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{DC322F}
\definecolor{magenta}{HTML}{D33682}
\definecolor{violet}{HTML}{6C71C4}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{268BD2}
\definecolor{cyan}{HTML}{2AA198}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{859900}


\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={
    typeof,new,true,false,catch,function,return,null,catch,switch,var,if,in,
    while,do,else,case,break, try},
  ndkeywords={class,export,boolean,throw,implements,import,this},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,list inside=codeList,number within=section]{codeBox}[1]{
   breakable,
   bottomrule at break=0pt,
   toprule at break=0pt,
   title=Code~\thetcbcounter: #1,
   colback=base2,
   colframe=base02,
   listing only,
   listing options={
     language=JavaScript,
     commentstyle=\color{base0},
     keywordstyle=\color{yellow},
     stringstyle=\color{blue},
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{base01},
     identifierstyle=\color{base02},
     ndkeywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,
     breaklines=true,
     breakautoindent=true,
     breakindent=30pt,
     escapeinside={~}{~},
     showstringspaces=false,
     captionpos=b
   },
   list entry=\thetcbcounter~~#1,
   before=\bigskip\noindent,
   fontupper=\singlespacing\vskip -1.5em
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{codeBox}
code here
the end command will produce the error when compiling
\end{codeBox}

\end{document}
```

When compiling, I get:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
               \tcb@lsttp@tcolorbox
l.85 \end{codeBox}
```

Comment: If I remove the first optional argument to `\newtcblisting` there is no problem.

Comment: Do you talk about `auto counter`?

Comment: Ok, I get it. `list inside` is the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @b3by Could you post a self-answer?

Comment: @JosephWright unfortunately I can't, I need 15 points at least.

Comment: @b3by Should have enough rep now!

Comment: Somehow I missed this question. Yes, this is an error. You can take the answer of @neverpanic for a temporary workaround. With `tcolorbox` version `3.03 (2014/05/16)` this bug is fixed. The new version should be available on CTAN next week.

Comment: By the way: You should push the accept-answer-button for @neverpanic when you come back to this site ... :-)

Answer (score 4):

The very same MWE doesn't compile (with the same error message) with `tcolorbox` 3.00 for me. I'm not an expert on this, but I think this might be a bug in the `tcolorbox` package. It works fine for me if I apply this patch to the `tcolorbox.sty` file:

```
diff --git a/texmf/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty b/texmf/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
index 4555182..c8ea54d 100644
--- a/texmf/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
+++ b/texmf/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
@@ -1186,7 +1186,7 @@
   \else%
     \csedef{tcb@lstof@#2}{\kvtcb@new@listof}%
     \csedef{tcb@lsttp@#2}{\kvtcb@new@listtype}%
-    \appto\tcb@new@colopt{,add to list={\csname tcb@lstof@\kvtcb@savedelimiter\endcsname}{\csname tcb@lsttp@\kvtcb@savedelimiter\endcsname}}%
+    \appto\tcb@new@colopt{,add to list={\csname tcb@lstof@#2\endcsname}{\csname tcb@lsttp@#2\endcsname}}%
   \fi%
   \kvtcb@init@hook%
 }%
```

Comment: If you think you've got a good patch, you should probably contact the author of `tcolorbox` directly about it.

Comment: I've seen the problem now. This patch is correct! The bug-fixed version `3.03 (2014/05/16)` is on its way to CTAN.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it. If the codeBox is defined as:

```
\newtcblisting[auto counter,list inside=codeList,number within=section]{codeBox}[1]{ ... }
```

my boxes are correctly compiled. There is a drawback, that is, codes will not be listed in the list of listings.